# Is signed right 1 (>> 1) the same as *0.5?

Tags: java

I am making a program in which I used `>> 1` and I'm wondering if using `*0.5` is exactly the same thing. I'm new to Java, so be easy on me.

Comment: One gives an integer while the other gives a double, so no, they are clearly not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fundamentally not the same because you can't perform bit shifting with non integer numbers. Therefore, doing something like `7 >> 1` will return 3, but `7 * 0.5` will return the proper `float` value `3.5`

Comment: It is essentially the same thing as the integer division `/2`, though.

Comment: @Kon what does bit shift do then to make 7 3 or 9 4

Comment: @tomjdog It only acts on integer operands. So it is using (essentially) integer divison. In java, 7/2 = 3, because dividing two integers must produce an integer result.

Comment: assylias: Valid point. -1>>1 is -1, -2 >>1 is -1, -3>>1 is -2, -4>>1 is -2, and so on. There's probably some compact algebraic notation for this involving the definition of two's complement, but I'm not quite awake enough to come up with it on the spur of the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all, `>>` is a bitwise shift, which is quite different than multiplication by 0.5 (division by 2 for that matter). While for some numbers you may get the same result for both operations, for others you don't. For example, `3 >> 1` equals 1, while `3 * 0.5` is 1.5.

Furthermore, for bitwise shift, the type of operand and return type are both `int`, but if you do `(int) * 0.5`, the resulting value will be of type `double`.

Comment: If you multiply an `int` by `0.5`, you get a `double`, not a `float`.